# R- Mutate is not mutating all values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to see if there is a way I can combine lines of code when mutating multiple values based on another value. However, when I use c() as a list, not all values are mutating, only some.  Is there something else I need to do, or do I need to have each mutate on an individual line?

Example data:

```
Category <- c("Additional Fees", "Additional Fees", "None", "None", "Package", "None")
Item <- c("20oz Upgrade", "Ice Cream", "20oz Upgrade", "Ice Cream", "Ice Cream", "20oz Upgrade")
df <- data.frame(Category, Item)
```

Longer code that works

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Category = ifelse(Item == "20oz Upgrade", "Additional Fees", Category)) %>% 
  mutate(Category = ifelse(Item == "Ice Cream", "Additional Fees", Category))
```

Combining mutate- but not all values are mutating- I would like to use this though (lines 5 and 6 of Category are not mutating for me).

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Category = ifelse(Item == c("20oz Upgrade", "Ice Cream"), "Additional Fees", Category))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `%in%` rather than `==` because you're checking if an item is in a vector of two rather than is equal too:

```r
df |> mutate(Category = ifelse(Item %in% c("20oz Upgrade", "Ice Cream"), "Additional Fees", Category))
```

Output:

```r
         Category         Item
1 Additional Fees 20oz Upgrade
2 Additional Fees    Ice Cream
3 Additional Fees 20oz Upgrade
4 Additional Fees    Ice Cream
5 Additional Fees    Ice Cream
6 Additional Fees 20oz Upgrade
```